# Restangular Promises in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, restangular, angular-promise

I have some SPA, where user can add, edit, view and delete items. All data keeps in JSON file. So, when I want to add/edit/delete some item, I use php code. It works fine.

I don't have problem with view and delete, There is something with add/edit.

So, how it works. On the main form I have a list with all items and button Create new item. When I click it, I go to another form with textfields. After I fill them, I click Create button on this form. As a result, new item is in JSON file, and I go back to the main form. BUT. There is an old list of items, without new one. The same thing happends when user edit item.

I know that it's all about promises. Restangular is async, so my code doesn't have time to process all I told him. I tried to figure it out by myself, but I just don't understand how it should be.

There is my controllers:

```
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, customers, ListService) {
   $scope.customers = customers;
   cust = customers;
   $scope.removeItem = function removeItem(index) {
       $scope.customers.splice(index, 1);
       ListService.saveData($scope.customers);
   };
});

app.controller('CreateController', function ($scope, customers, ListService) {

   $scope.customers = customers;
   $scope.createItem = function createItem(item) {
       $scope.customers = customers;
       $scope.customers.push(item);
       ListService.saveData($scope.customers);
   };
});
app.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, details, ListService) {
   $scope.item = details[0];
   var keep = {};
   for (var key in details[0]) {
       keep[key] = details[0][key];
   }

   $scope.updateItem = function updateItem() {
       $scope.customers = cust;
       var ind = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) {
           if (($scope.customers[i].id == keep.id)) {
               ind = i;
           }
       }
       if (ind != -1) {
           $scope.customers.splice(ind, 1, $scope.item);
       }
       ListService.saveData($scope.customers);
   };
});
```

Comment: if i well understand the problem you should try to update the $scope......try with $scope.$apply() -- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Comment: @icchio no, it's not what I need. But thanks foryour reply.

Comment: what does `ListService.saveData()` ? can you add its code ? and do you have any  kind of error message on your browsers console ?